# How to have nginx proxy websockets without continuous connection to back end server?

Tags: apache, nginx, websocket

I currently have a server running apache httpd 2.2 serving ~1000 websocket connections.  I'm trying to scale this up to around ~10K websockets on the the same hardware.  I thought I'd be able to place an nginx reverse proxy on the front end, and that nginx would only connect to the backend when there was incoming traffic, and would maintain the connection to the outside world.   However, right now the connection seems to continuous (i.e., once the websocket upgrade is complete, a httpd process is tied up until the connection is broken.   Am I misunderstanding how nginx should do websockets proxying, or do I have something misconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

NGINX supports WebSockets by creating a tunnel between the client and the backend server and so the nginx will not terminate the connections to the backend/frontend until the client/server terminates the connections.

See: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ for more info.